# What is the difference between Azure Function App Settings and Application Settings

Tags: azure, azure-functions

When setting up an Azure function you have the option to add 'Function App Settings' and also 'Application Settings' and I am confused about when you would use one over the other - can anybody explain the correct use-cases for each of the Setting types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could get the answer from [How to manage a function app in the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings).

> **Function app settings**: where you can update the Functions **runtime version** used by your function app. It is also where you manage the **host keys** used to restrict HTTP access to all functions hosted by the function app.
>
> **Application settings** blade is where you configure and **manage framework versions, remote debugging, app settings, and connection strings**. When you integrate your function app with other Azure and third-party services, you can modify those settings here.